# Java final static field is null at first usage

Tags: java, logging, static-initialization

There is a class which should store logs in a local file, which is hardcoded into the program.

The logic for initializing it as follows:

```java
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Util {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Util.class.getName());
    private static final FileHandler filehandler = createFileHandler();

    private static FileHandler createFileHandler(){
        FileHandler handler;
        try {
            handler = new FileHandler("security.log", 0, 1, true);
            LOGGER.addHandler(filehandler);
        } catch (IOException | SecurityException e) {
            handler = null;
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Unable to create Security log!");
        }
        return handler;
    }
    
    public static String use_util(){
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Utils are used!");
        return "It's just I don't know.. a string, man.";
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(Util.use_util());
    }
}
```

Upon the first call of `use_util` there is a nullpointerexception however, stating that `LOGGER` is null:

```
$javac Util.java
$java -Xmx128M -Xms16M Util
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.logging.Logger.addHandler(Logger.java:1748)
    at Util.createFileHandler(Util.java:14)
    at Util.<clinit>(Util.java:8)
```

According to the Java spec [section 12.4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2) :

> Then, initialize the final class variables and fields of interfaces whose values are compile-time >constant expressions (§8.3.2.1, §9.3.1, §13.4.9, §15.28).
> ...
>
> Next, execute either the class variable initializers and static initializers of the class, or the field >initializers of the interface, in textual order, as though they were a single block.

So based on that, `LOGGER` should be initialized before `fileHandler` is. Despite that, `LOGGER` seems to be null when the `fileHandler` is initialized...

Why is that?
How can the initialization order be forced?

Comment: You should always provide complete stacktraces.  It is hard to understand what is going on if you edit them for brevity ... or for whatever reason.

Comment: I extended the code to be runnable.. thank you for pointing it out, I'Ll extend the traces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

at java.util.logging.Logger.addHandler(Logger.java:1748)
```

From the way I read this, the class fields are not an issue here.
`LOGGER` is not null, the call towards `LOGGER.addHandler()` is executed, but fails internally.

This is because you pass `filehandler` into the call, not the handler `handler` that you just initialized in the line before.
Since you're still within the initialization execution for `filehandler` at that point, it is still `null`.